# Pull-right element becomes non clickable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a small CSS issue here that I'm unable to understand.

I'm using the "pull-right" Bootstrap class to enable those elements to be on the same line : "Se souvenir de moi" and "Mot de passe oublié ?"

It turns out that "Mot de passe oublié ?" becomes unclickable. It's seams that there's an element over him...

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
.container.center-container
  %div.col-lg-4.col-lg-offset-4.custom-jumbotron
    %h2.connexion-title Bienvenue

    = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: "Email"
        = f.input :password, required: false, label: false, placeholder: "Mot de passe"
        - if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations'
          = link_to "Mot de passe oublié ?", new_password_path(resource_name), class: "pull-right"
        = f.input :remember_me, label: "Se souvenir de moi", as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, "Se connecter", class: "btn btn-lg btn-block btn-orange login-button", style: "background-color:#D5420F; color: white; border: 0;"
```

------- Edit ----

Here it is in plain HTML. I have then the same issue using JSbin and the 2.3.2 Bootstrap library :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container center-container">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 custom-jumbotron">
  <h2 class="connexion-title">Bienvenue</h2>
  <div class="form-inputs">
   <div class="form-group email optional user_email">
    <input class="string email optional form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group password optional user_password">
    <input class="password optional form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
   </div>
   <a class="pull-right" href="/users/password/new">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
   <div class="form-group boolean optional user_remember_me">
    <div class="checkbox">
     <input value="0" type="hidden" name="user[remember_me]">
     <label class="boolean optional" for="user_remember_me">
      <input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]" id="user_remember_me">
      Se souvenir de moi
     </label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle to help us helping you?

Comment: you can use http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net - both let you add bootstrap, I think jsbin is better

Comment: Since i'm using HAML and Simpleform together, they don't seem to work.

Comment: Since it is a bootstrap/CSS issue adding the generated code (as seen in the browser) will be fine.

Comment: could you then link to your JSbin?

Comment: Would it work like this : https://jsbin.com/gamoyuraxi/edit?html,output ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with HALM, but if you can change the `display` property of the following div

```
<div class="checkbox">
```

to `inline` The link with `pull-right` will not be covered by the checkbox.

You could add a helper class for that in your css and add that to the div with class `checkbox` .

```css
.display-inline {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container center-container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 custom-jumbotron">
    <h2 class="connexion-title">Bienvenue</h2>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <div class="form-group email optional user_email"><input class="string email optional form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email" /></div>
      <div class="form-group password optional user_password"><input class="password optional form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" /></div>
      <a class="pull-right" href="/users/password/new">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
      <div class="form-group boolean optional user_remember_me"><div class="checkbox display-inline"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="user[remember_me]" /><label class="boolean optional" for="user_remember_me"><input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]" id="user_remember_me" />Se souvenir de moi</label></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```